# I2C from two masters (ATtiny85, ESP8266) to one slave (ATmega328)

Tags: esp8266, i2c, atmega328, wire-library, attiny85

I've been working on a project with I2C protocol where an ATmega328 (Arduino) configured as slave, receives messages from an ATtiny (ATtiny85, ATTinyCore by SpenceKonde) configured as master, or from an ESP8266 (ESP-01, Arduino core) configured as master.

All using the standard wire library, powered with 3.3v (LM1117 regulator), SDA and SCL 4.7kohms pull-ups.
The ESP pins used are RX and TX, with 330ohms pull-ups.

Individually, it works (ATtiny to ATmega; ESP to ATmega), but when i connect the three on the same bus, after the first message it stops working and the ATmega doesn't receive more messages.

---

Code (modified for readability)

ATmega slave:

```
#include <Wire.h>

const int ADDRESS = 56;

void receiveEvent() {
    Serial.println(Wire.read());
}

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    Wire.begin(MY_ADDRESS);
    Wire.onReceive(receiveEvent);
}

void loop() {
}
```

ESP master:

```
#include <Wire.h>

const int DISPLAY_ADDRESS = 56;
const int PACKET_SIZE = 1;
const int SDA_PIN = 1;
const int SCL_PIN = 3;

void setup(){
    Wire.begin(SDA_PIN, SCL_PIN);
}

void loop() {
    byte packet[PACKET_SIZE];
    packet[0] = 'e';
    Wire.beginTransmission(DISPLAY_ADDRESS);
    Wire.write(packet, PACKET_SIZE);
    Wire.endTransmission();
    delay(2500;)
}
```

ATtiny master:

```
#include <Wire.h>

const int DISPLAY_ADDRESS = 56;
const int PACKET_SIZE = 1;
// SDA = 0; attiny85 pin 5
// SCL = 2; attiny85 pin 7

void setup() {
    Wire.begin();
}

void loop() {
    byte packet[PACKET_SIZE];
    packet[0] = 'a';
    Wire.beginTransmission(DISPLAY_ADDRESS);
    Wire.write(packet, PACKET_SIZE);
    Wire.endTransmission();
    delay(1000);
}
```

---

After some research I found out that the wire library can only work with a single master, is this correct? And the esp can only work in master mode.

Am I doing something wrong, or is this simply not possible?

Are there any protocol alternatives for this design?
A single device that only cares about receiving messages, and multiple other devices that only care about sending messages to the central.

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Apparently someone made a ESP8266 I2C slave library: [https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/1330#issuecomment-276210394](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/issues/1330#issuecomment-276210394). If this is true, I'd go with it and make the 328 the only master. There is a multimaster mode in I2C, but if the ESP cannot enable it then I think it is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your implementation. If you REALLY need 2 masters there should be a way to make it work.

At the moment the problem that I can see is that both masters continually poll the I2C data lines, effectively this means that the data on the lines is all mixed up and scrambled together. What could do is have 2 wires connecting both masters. When one of the masters is writing to the slave pull the line high, the other master should read this line as high, and not write data to the I2C lines. When the line drops low, it should then take its turn to write to the AtMega. This method would ensure only one master is using the data lines at one time. The implementation is pretty rudimentary and fairly crude and I'm aware the ATtiny may not have enough pins for this.

The best way to solve your problem I think is to have the ESP8266 as your single master, with your ATtiny and ATmega as slaves. Make the ESP poll the ATtiny for its data/instructions it wants to pass to the Atmega, and get the ESP to pass on this data or instructions to the ATmega along with its own data and instructions. This should be a robust and reliable fix.

Comment: When I started I had almost no knowledge of I2C or Wire lib, I just assumed that would be possible to have multiple masters and slaves.

For your first solution, it requires one wire for each master, correct? If I latter want to add another send device, it would require 3 extra pins on each master?

For your second solution, I think this is what I'll do, as I have no more pins available on the ESP for the previous solution.

If I started all from scratch, what would be a good implementation?

Comment: Well yes if you want each master to be able to pause every other master then yes, you'd need a line from each one to each of the others, you can imagine tgat this wiring would quickly become over complex. However there is another way to avoid having 2 lines and only having one. You give one of the masters greater priority.  Holding a single line high when it wants to talk, letting the other talk the rest of the time. This actually becomes very complicated on the coding side of things though (much more so than you'd initially think), so is best to avoid.

Answer (score 3):

If you have 1 receive only device, and 2 send-only devices, why not make the receive-only device the master, but have it poll (periodically, repeatedly ask) the slave devices to send any data they have pending. That way, there is only one master, and it only asks for data when it's ready (that is, not receiving from some other device.)

One purpose of a master/slave bus system is to avoid contention (two or more devices talking at the same time.) The master tells each device when to send, and only listens after it asks.

Comment: The ESP8266 only supports master mode (I think), so at least one of the send-only devices has to be master.